# How can I change this code to skip already chosen numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is a game. Guess 4 digits of a code, game outputs amount of correct digits in the correct place and amount of correct digits in wrong place.

Assume the code was 4405 and guess 4444
It should output 2, 0 but instead outputs 2, 2
Logically I want the program to not compare to numbers in the code set as true/matched correctly. How can I change this code to accomplish this?

> Assume arr is an array made up of 4 falses and guess1,2,3,4 are the 4 digits of your guess

```
  wronPlace= 0
  if arr[0]== False:
      if guess1== code[1]:
          arr[0]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
      elif guess1== code[2]:
          arr[0]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
      elif guess1== code[3]:
          arr[0]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
  if arr[1]== False:
      if guess2== code[0]:
          arr[1]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
      elif guess2== code[2]:
          arr[1]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
      elif guess2== code[3]:
          arr[1]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
  if arr[2]== False:
      if guess3== code[0]:
          arr[2]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
      elif guess3== code[1]:    
          arr[2]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
      elif guess3== code[3]:
          arr[2]== True
          wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
  if arr[3]== False:
     if guess4== code[0]:
         arr[3]== True
         wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
     elif guess4== code[1]:
         arr[3]== True
         wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
     elif guess4== code[2]:
         arr[3]== True
         wronPlace= (wronPlace+1)
```

Comment: Try searching SO for "codebreaker game", you'll find other questions about implementing this (it's a common exercise). I'll bet some of them had the same problem.

Comment: Wow..... this was a lot of code. You need to implement loops.

Comment: Anton could you please help me on doing so?

Comment: @Aura Soon, if  no one else does before.

Comment: Barmar I have and they are not completing the same task as me. Theirs is one of simple comparison and output of "XXXX" mine is only of the logic and position of the numbers. @Anton I have been stuck on this for a while and asked several platforms while manipulating the code. None of which have worked. If you would know how I can use iteration and in what form it would be EXTREMELY helpful! Thank you

Comment: @Aura I was going to help out a bit but now I see there are two answers that give you something to continue with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from random import choice
from string import digits
from textwrap import dedent


def get_four_digit_number(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if 1000 <= num <= 9999:
                return str(num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    secret_code = ''.join(choice(digits) for _ in range(4))

    while True:
        guess = get_four_digit_number('Enter your 4-digit guess: ')
        correct = []
        incorrect = []
        for a, b in zip(guess, secret_code):
            if a == b:
                correct.append('^')
                incorrect.append(' ')
            else:
                correct.append(' ')
                incorrect.append('!')

        print(dedent("""
                   {} <-- Incorrect
            Guess: {}
                   {} <-- Correct
        """.format(''.join(incorrect), guess, ''.join(correct))))

        if correct == list('^^^^'):
            print('Nice guess! The secret code was {}'.format(secret_code))
            break
```

Output example:

```
Enter your 4-digit guess: 1111

       !!!! <-- Incorrect
Guess: 1111
            <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 2222

       !!!! <-- Incorrect
Guess: 2222
            <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3333

        !!  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3333
       ^  ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3443

        !!  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3443
       ^  ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3553

        !!  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3553
       ^  ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3663

        !!  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3663
       ^  ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3773

        !!  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3773
       ^  ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3883

        !!  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3883
       ^  ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3993

         !  <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3993
       ^^ ^ <-- Correct

Enter your 4-digit guess: 3903

            <-- Incorrect
Guess: 3903
       ^^^^ <-- Correct

Nice guess! The secret code was 3903
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that it outputs digits compared to only another. it needs to compare to ALL and output the position while skipping doubles

Comment: it should output "The amount of correct digits is: ...." "The amount of correct digits in the wrong place is: ..."

Comment: this means that guess[0] compares to code[0], code[1] and so on

Comment: if I input 4888 and the code is 5805 I do not want the 3 eights to compare to code[1]. This would cause the wrong impression as it could go over the same digits over 4 times

Comment: In that example, the comparisons are 4->5, 8->8, 8->0, 8->5. The three eights (indexes 1, 2, 3 of the guess 4888) are not being compared to the 5 (code[0]).

Comment: the problem is that the second eight is being compared to the 8 in 5805

Comment: read my code above and rules thoroughly. wronPlace is NOT meant to allow repeated numbers when the number has already been compared and saved as correct aka True

Answer (score 2):

Your code is much more complex than what it needs to be. You can use a `for` loop to achieve what you want.

```
guess = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
answer = 2245

answer = str(answer)
corr_place, wrong_place = 0, 0
for i, g in enumerate(guess):
    if g in answer:
        if g == answer[i]:
            corr_place += 1
        else:
            wrong_place += 1

print("Correct position:", corr_place)
print("Wrong position:", wrong_place)
```

But a more Pythonic solution would be something that uses list comprehensions:

```
guess = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
answer = 2245

answer = str(answer)
results = [g == d for g, d in zip(guess, answer) if g in answer]
corr = sum(results)

print("Correct position:", corr)
print("Wrong position:", len(results) - corr)
```

Comment: corr= correct digits in correct place wronPlace= correct digits in the wrong place

Comment: not guesses but position of numbers. Guesses is something completely different in the code

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also, please check the examples you have given. Shouldn't the first example return 2 digits in the wrong place?

Comment: that's the weird thing. The code outputs 1 correct digit in the wrong place even though the same number has been already compared

Comment: Your code has a typo in it towards the end. That's why it's behaving oddly. All the more reason to use `for` loops!

Comment: what is the typo?

Comment: In the `if` loop for `arr[3]` while calculating `wronPlace`, you compare with 0, 2, and 3 indices of `code`. It should be 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: but it it still repeating numbers. The code this time was 6294 and guess was 6666 but it output "1 digit in correct spot" but "3 digits in the wrong place"

Comment: I want it so if one is matched to another then that piece of code is not compared again.